# Creating a database context using the database first approach with entityframework core.

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I want to be able to create a database context with entityframework core in my webapi project using the database first approach.
When I create like this it works very well

```
    public class TestingContext : DbContext
        {
            public TestingContext(DbContextOptions<TestingContext> options)
                : base(options)
            {
            }

            public TestingContext()
            {
            }

            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Integrated Security=False;User Id=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");

            }

            public DbSet<Information> Information { get; set; }
            public DbSet<ArticleUser> ArticleUser { get; set; }

        }
```

I had to add  the line services.AddDbContext to make it work.

```
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddCors();
            //using Dependency Injection
            services.AddSingleton<Ixxx, xxx>();

            // Add framework services.

            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
            services.AddDbContext<TestingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            // Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Articles API", Version = "v1" });
            });

        }
```

If I remove this method from my TestingContext

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Integrated Security=False;User Id=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");

    }
```

I get the error below.

No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. 
A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or 
by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, 
then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its 
constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Why do I need to pass my connection string to the database in two places before it can pull my data. Please assist. I am new to the core. The two places are configure services method and the context itself.

Comment: Is your DbContext located in a different assembly? And do you have a project.json (VS2015) project or a csproject (VS2017)?

Comment: No it is not located in a different assembly. I created a class within the same project. Yes I do have project.json (vs 2015)

Comment: This error typically comes, when `DbContext` is located in a class library rather than inside the ASP.NET Core project and when one calls `dotnet ef database scaffold ...` from this class library, see [.NET Standard Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#common-errors)

Comment: Remove your parameterless constructor. Optionally you can remove your `OnConfiguring` method.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** Remove parameterized constructor and OnConfiguring. Result:

```
public class TestingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Information> Information { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArticleUser> ArticleUser { get; set; }
}
```

**Option 2:** Remove parameterized constructor and options in `ConfigureServices` in `AddDbContext`
Result:

In `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddDbContext<TestingContext>();
```

In `TestingDbContext.cs`

```
public class TestingDdContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Integrated Security=False;User Id=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
    }

    public DbSet<Information> Information { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArticleUser> ArticleUser { get; set; }
}
```

**Option 3:** A parametric constructor is needed to create factory. Example:

```
public class TestDdContext : DbContext
{
    public TestDdContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    //TODO: DbSets
}

public class TestDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<TestDdContext>
{
    public TestDdContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
    {
        var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();

        contextOptions.UseSqlServer("...");

        return new TestDdContext(contextOptions.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: i tested and added a comment about my finding.

Comment: Option 1 does not work but option 2 works and I decided to go with it. Is it possible to read the connection string from the json file. optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Integrated Security=False;User Id=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating tests, do you need a backing Sql database? Would the In-memory provider not serve you better?

```
options.UseInMemoryDatabase("database-name");
```

For this reason, I'd ditch using the `OnConfiguring` method, and rely on passing the `DbContextOptions` to your constructor

> Side note, you have to consider *what* you are testing - are you testing your code that is dependent on your `DbContext`, or are you testing your `DbContext` itself - if there is no custom logic and you are merely extending the `DbContext`, there may not be enough value in writing tests for it - and you're not responsible for testing EFCore itself.